# Checking to See if Next Page exists Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently learning to write a **scraper** using BeautifulSoup.  So far, my code below works fine, except for a few issues.  First of all, to explain I'm currently scraping the player data from the Fold.it project.  Since there are multiple pages that need to be scraped, I've been using this code block to look for the next page at the end of the loop.

```
   next_link = soup.find(class_='active', title='Go to next page')
   url_next = "http://www.fold.it" + next_link['href'] ### problem line???
   print url_next
```

Unfortunately, on occasion I'll get a result such as this: [image: 1]

From what I can deduce, for some reason the next page link isn't parsed.  I'm not sure if it's because of the particular website, the code I wrote, or something completely different.  So far, I've tried writing code that would check to see if it returns a NoneType, but it would still error.

The ideal behavior I'm looking for would be to scrape until the last page.  However, if an error did occur, to retry that same page.  Any ideas, input, or obvious mistakes I'm making would be highly appreciated!

Full code below:

```
import os
import urllib2
import csv
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_next = 'http://www.fold.it/portal/players/s_all'
url_last = ''

today_string = time.strftime('%m_%d_%Y')
location = '/home/' + 'daily_soloist_' + today_string + '.csv'

mode = 'a' if os.path.exists(location) else 'w'
with open(location, mode) as my_csv:
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url_next).read(), "lxml")
    if url_next == url_last:
        print "Scraping Complete"
        break

    for row in soup('tr', {'class':'even'}):
        cells = row('td')

  #current rank
        rank = cells[0].text

  #finds first text node - user name
        name = cells[1].a.find(text=True).strip()

  #separates ranking
        rank1, rank2 = cells[1].find_all("span")

  #total global score
        score = row('td')[2].string

        data = [[int(str(rank[1:])), name.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), int(str(rank1.text)), int(str(rank2.text)), int(str(score))]]

  #writes to csv
        database = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
        database.writerows(data)  


   next_link = soup.find(class_='active', title='Go to next page')
   url_next = "http://www.fold.it" + next_link['href'] ### problem line???
   print url_next

   last_link = soup.find(class_='active', title = 'Go to last page')
   url_last = "http://www.fold.it" + last_link['href']
```

Comment: I would dump the entire page when you hit an error like that.  There is a possibility they are rate-limiting you, and if so, they might display a message saying as much.

Comment: @jeffcarey what do you mean by 'dump the page'?  Like save the current page upon error?  I'm trying to learn the lingo, so apologies if this is a simple question

Comment: It could mean to save it to a file but in this case I meant just print it to the screen if that's convenient for you.  The idea is you want to get a quick glance and see if the site is not giving you the data you normally expect to receive.

Answer (score 0):

For a fix you can put in the following `try:` `except:` block.  (you should add more error handling than I did)  If the try fails, you don't change the `url_next` value.  However be careful, if you get an error on the same page you will be in an endless loop.

```
try:
    if url_next == url_last:
        print "Scraping Complete"
        break

    for row in soup('tr', {'class':'even'}):
        cells = row('td')

        #current rank
        rank = cells[0].text

        #finds first text node - user name
        name = cells[1].a.find(text=True).strip()

        #separates ranking
        rank1, rank2 = cells[1].find_all("span")

        #total global score
        score = row('td')[2].string

        data = [[int(str(rank[1:])), name.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), int(str(rank1.text)), int(str(rank2.text)), int(str(score))]]

        #writes to csv
        database = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
        database.writerows(data)  


    next_link = soup.find(class_='active', title='Go to next page')
    url_next = "http://www.fold.it" + next_link['href'] ### problem line???

except:  #if the above bombs out, maintain the same url_next
    print "problem with this page, try again"

print url_next
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying! Thanks for the Try/Except example.  I finally figured out the issue and it wasn't my code, it was the site I'm scraping from.  Using a Try/Except allowed me to just bypass empty pages.